# Converting to Markdown why not working properly without print() function pandas 1.0

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying this example [Converting to Markdown](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.0.0/whatsnew/v1.0.0.html#converting-to-markdown). Table markdown not formatting properly without `print()` function.

```py
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2, 3], "B": [1, 2, 3]}, index=['a', 'a', 'b'])
>>> print(df.to_markdown())
|    |   A |   B |
|:---|----:|----:|
| a  |   1 |   1 |
| a  |   2 |   2 |
| b  |   3 |   3 |

>>> df.to_markdown()       # Without print function gave `\n` instead new line
'|    |   A |   B |\n|:---|----:|----:|\n| a  |   1 |   1 |\n| a  |   2 |   2 |\
n| b  |   3 |   3 |'
```

Comment: try executing `df.to_string()` v/s `print(df.to_string())`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

to_markdown() function returns a string, it does not print it